# Unable to click a desired button in Protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

I am trying to click a button using Protractor - my HTML looks like this:

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="app-nav" style="display: block;">
                <unity-navigation _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c2=""><div _ngcontent-c2="" class="nav">
    <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="nav-primary" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <ul _ngcontent-c2="">
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><li _ngcontent-c2="" class="active nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
                    <i _ngcontent-c2="" class="fa fa-home nav-icon" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa fa-home,nav-icon"></i><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span _ngcontent-c2="" class="nav-label">Home</span>
            </li><li _ngcontent-c2="" class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
                    <i _ngcontent-c2="" class="fa fa-arrow-right nav-icon" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa fa-arrow-right,nav-icon"></i><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span _ngcontent-c2="" class="nav-label">Send</span>
            </li><li _ngcontent-c2="" class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
                    <i _ngcontent-c2="" class="fa fa-check nav-icon" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa fa-check,nav-icon"></i><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span _ngcontent-c2="" class="nav-label">Review</span>
```

I am trying to click a send button mentioned under Span tag..

Here is my code:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        // Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be visible on the dom.
        var scbutton =element.all(by.css('.fa.fa-arrow-right.nav-icon'));
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf('scbutton'), 5000);
```

Trying to check the visibility of a button - but it is showing below error:

**Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import {browser, by, element, protractor} from 'protractor';

export class NameofClass {

    constructor() {
        this.scbutton = element(by.css('.fa.fa-arrow-right.nav-icon'));
    }

    async CheckvisibilityOf() {
        await browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(this.scbutton), 5000,
            'Scbutton not appear during 5 seconds');
    }
}
```